# EMI Filter for Buck Converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, emc, emi-filtering

I'm trying to design an EMI filter for a buck converter and I'm following steps on: [AN-2162](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva489c/snva489c.pdf)

Here is the question:

At page:6, for the Cf capacitor; two different capacitor values are calculated and highest value is taken(Cfa, Cfb). In my situation, calculations for Cfa results a negative cap. value.

Since there is no negative capacitance, should I neglect this result or take it as a positive value?

Here is the calculation:

Cin=2uF(0.000002F)

L=1mH(0.001H)

fs=30kHz

for Cfa:

0.000002 / ((0.000002) x (0.001) x (((2 x 3.14 x 30000)/10)^2)-1)

0.000002 / ((0.000002) x (0.001) x (355000000))-1

0.000002 / (0.71-1)

0.000002 / -0.29

= -6.89uF

Comment: Is that from section 4.3 which says "Pick the higher value determined by the following two formulas" and gives an alternative formula?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, I got one of them negative.

Comment: And so which one is the higher value? Use that. (E.g. 5 is higher than -10.)

Comment: -10 is not a valid value for capacitance, that's why I ask for it, I thought maybe minus sign has no importance here and it may become: 10 is higher than 5

Comment: Please check the APEC [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202017.pdf) I taught in 2017 in which I show in slide 80 how to design an EMI filter for a buck and how to optimally damp it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really sure you did the computation correctly?
In equation (5) Cfb can be negative only if is negative either of

- Lf : negative inductor? no, check
- The thing after that? no, it's *squared* so it can't, check

Given that there are no complex numbers in that formula I don't get how you can get a negative value

Comment: I'm sorry, Cfa is negative.

Comment: @DasD. Show how.

Comment: @winny values are edited